# Table header only aligned with first column

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a table to display a list of monsters, the issue I am having is the headers section is only lining up with the first column

```js
const { data } = useFetchData('http://localhost:3500/monster');
return (
  <div className="App">
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow className="Table-Headers">
            <TableHeader name="Name" />
            <TableHeader name="Type" />
            <TableHeader name="Size" />
            <TableHeader name="HP" />
            <TableHeader name="CR" />
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data &&
            data.map((monster) => (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell align="left">{monster.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">{monster.type}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">{monster.size}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">{monster.hit_points}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">{monster.challenge_rating}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">
                  <button>EDIT</button>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">
                  <button>DELETE</button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </div>
);
```

```
function TableHeader(params) {
  return (
    <TableCell className="Table-Headers">
      <strong>{params.name}</strong>
      <div className="Sorting-Buttons">
        <button>UP</button>
        <button>DOWN</button>
      </div>
    </TableCell>
  );
}
```

[image]

You can see what it looks like here, I need the headers to properly line up with their respective columns is there something wrong with how I am adding the header cell?

EDIT: At request of David Thomas, the final html for  and  I only showed one row cause there is 1086 entries

```html
<thead class="MuiTableHead-root css-15wwp11-MuiTableHead-root">
  <tr
    class="
      MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-head
      Table-Headers
      css-1q1u3t4-MuiTableRow-root
    "
  >
    <th
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        Table-Headers
        css-1ygcj2i-MuiTableCell-root
      "
      scope="col"
    >
      <strong>Name</strong>
      <div class="Sorting-Buttons">
        <button>UP</button><button>DOWN</button>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        Table-Headers
        css-1ygcj2i-MuiTableCell-root
      "
      scope="col"
    >
      <strong>Type</strong>
      <div class="Sorting-Buttons">
        <button>UP</button><button>DOWN</button>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        Table-Headers
        css-1ygcj2i-MuiTableCell-root
      "
      scope="col"
    >
      <strong>Size</strong>
      <div class="Sorting-Buttons">
        <button>UP</button><button>DOWN</button>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        Table-Headers
        css-1ygcj2i-MuiTableCell-root
      "
      scope="col"
    >
      <strong>HP</strong>
      <div class="Sorting-Buttons">
        <button>UP</button><button>DOWN</button>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        Table-Headers
        css-1ygcj2i-MuiTableCell-root
      "
      scope="col"
    >
      <strong>CR</strong>
      <div class="Sorting-Buttons">
        <button>UP</button><button>DOWN</button>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        css-1ygcj2i-MuiTableCell-root
      "
      scope="col"
    >
      EDIT
    </th>
    <th
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        css-1ygcj2i-MuiTableCell-root
      "
      scope="col"
    >
      DELETE
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="MuiTableBody-root css-apqrd9-MuiTableBody-root">
  <tr class="MuiTableRow-root css-1q1u3t4-MuiTableRow-root">
    <td
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root
        MuiTableCell-body
        MuiTableCell-alignLeft
        MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        css-1ex1afd-MuiTableCell-root
      "
    >
      Aatxe
    </td>
    <td
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root
        MuiTableCell-body
        MuiTableCell-alignLeft
        MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        css-1ex1afd-MuiTableCell-root
      "
    >
      celestial
    </td>
    <td
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root
        MuiTableCell-body
        MuiTableCell-alignLeft
        MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        css-1ex1afd-MuiTableCell-root
      "
    >
      Large
    </td>
    <td
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root
        MuiTableCell-body
        MuiTableCell-alignLeft
        MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        css-1ex1afd-MuiTableCell-root
      "
    >
      105
    </td>
    <td
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root
        MuiTableCell-body
        MuiTableCell-alignLeft
        MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        css-1ex1afd-MuiTableCell-root
      "
    >
      5
    </td>
    <td
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root
        MuiTableCell-body
        MuiTableCell-alignLeft
        MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        css-1ex1afd-MuiTableCell-root
      "
    >
      <button>EDIT</button>
    </td>
    <td
      class="
        MuiTableCell-root
        MuiTableCell-body
        MuiTableCell-alignLeft
        MuiTableCell-sizeMedium
        css-1ex1afd-MuiTableCell-root
      "
    >
      <button>DELETE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You have 5 TableHeaders and 7 TableCells.

Comment: What does the produced HTML look like?

Comment: @RobMoll adding extra headers, leads to the same issue

Comment: @DavidThomas I edited the post there with the final html the page shows

Comment: Can you post what styles for`Table-Headers` and `Sorting-Buttons` have?

Comment: @hotcakedev
`.Table-Headers {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.Sorting-Buttons {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
}`
I needed to use flex because by default the table headers where vertical rather than horizontal

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `TableHead` has 5 `TableCell`, but each `TableRow` has 7 `TableCell`.

So you need to make sure if the `TableHead` and `TableRow` has the same number of `TableCell` each.

```
...
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeader name="Name" />
              <TableHeader name="Type" />
              <TableHeader name="Size" />
              <TableHeader name="HP" />
              <TableHeader name="CR" />
              // Try to use 2 empty TableCell
              <TableCell />
              <TableCell />
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            ...
```

And also since each `TableCell` is aligned left, so you need to add `align="left"` to the `TableCell` inside `TableHeader` component.

```
function TableHeader(params) {
  return (
    <TableCell align="left" className="Table-Headers">
      <strong>{params.name}</strong>
      <div className="Sorting-Buttons">
        <button>UP</button>
        <button>DOWN</button>
      </div>
    </TableCell>
  );
}
```

Please make sure if you removed the `Table-Headers` class name from `TableRow` in `TableHead`. It should not be `flex`.

Comment: I updated my code with two empty cells and then two filled cells the same behaviour occurs except now the first column is as wide as 7 headers

Comment: @BobbyBorn2L8 Updated

Comment: Yeah that didn't do anything, the header renders before the body due to an API call, is it maybe to do with that? Like the body renders and the header does not adjust to match up with the content

Comment: One sec. Let's get into a chat.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/239739/mui-table-line-up?tab=general